# How come my hostname isn't set to the FQDN with cloud-init when using `prefer_fqdn_over_hostname`?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

[`prefer_fqdn_over_hostname` is documented as](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#set-hostname),

> If both `fqdn` and `hostname` are set, it is distro dependent whether `hostname` or `fqdn` is used, unless the **`prefer_fqdn_over_hostname` option is `true` and `fqdn` is set it will force the use of FQDN in all distros**, and if false then it will force the `hostname` use.

In my `cloud-init.cfg` I have,

```
hostname: "host-10-2-65-89"
fqdn: "host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build."
prefer_fqdn_over_hostname: true
```

But when I run this my hostname is set to `host-10-2-65-89`. Here is the log, and you can see it explicitly says `host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.`

```
249 - cc_set_hostname.py[DEBUG]: Setting the hostname to host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build. (host-10-2-65-89)
250 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /etc/hostname (quiet=False)
250 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 7 bytes from /etc/hostname
250 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /etc/hostname - wb: [644] 16 bytes
250 - __init__.py[DEBUG]: Non-persistently setting the system hostname to host-10-2-65-89
250 - subp.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['hostname', 'host-10-2-65-89'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
256 - atomic_helper.py[DEBUG]: Atomically writing to file /var/lib/cloud/data/set-hostname (via temporary file /var/lib/cloud/data/tmpaxqv667c) - w: [644] 80 bytes/chars
```

The contents of `/var/lib/cloud/data/set-hostname`

```json
{
 "fqdn": "host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.",
 "hostname": "host-10-2-65-89"
}
```

The contents of `/var/lib/cloud/data/previous-hostname`

```
host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.
```

I'm using `Cloud-init v. 21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1`

---

I've tried deleting all but the FQDN and it still doesn't set the `/etc/hostname` to the fqdn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**This is a bug in `cloud-init`, I've filed it upstream as Bug #1966533**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1966533)

I was getting silent failures because the hostname was

```
host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.
```

Instead of

```
host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build
```

What actually happens is,

```shell
$ sudo hostname host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.
hostname: the specified hostname is invalid
```

---

Background, what I was actually doing was using Terraform,

```
fqdn: "${fqdn}"
```

And then setting the `fqdn` like this,

```
fqdn = openstack_networking_port_v2.port_company.dns_assignment[0].fqdn
```

But the problem is the terraform was return the actual FQDN,

```
host-10-2-65-89.openstack.build.
```

But you can't provide that to hostname. My solution was to remove the dot (`.`) with [`trimsuffix`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/trimsuffix)

```
fqdn = trimsuffix(
  openstack_networking_port_v2.port_company.dns_assignment[0].fqdn,
  "."
)
```